# angular js: Error: $ is not defined in http post

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to post values from a form. Form has two fields- name and email. I have setup the controller as well but when i try to post, error is shown.

```
<form name="save" ng-submit="sap.saved(save.$valid)" novalidate>

        <div class="form-group" >
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" ng-model="sap.name" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" >
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" ng-model="sap.email" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="save.$invalid || sap.dataLoading">Save</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

My controller is:

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('myApp.saved', [])

        .controller('dataController', function($scope, $http) {
            var sap = this;

            $scope.post = {};
            $scope.post.login = [];
            $scope.sap = {};
            $scope.index = '';

            var url = 'save.php';

            sap.saved = function(isValid) 
            {
                if (isValid) 
                {
                    $http({
                      method: 'post',
                      url: url,
                      data: $.param({'user' : $scope.sap }),
                      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                    })
                    .then(function(response) 
                    {
                            // success
                            alert('success');
                    }, 
                    function(response) 
                    { 
                        // failed
                        alert('failed');
                    });
                }
            };

        });

})();
```

When i submit, $ is not defined is shown. I'm pretty much new in angular. Can anyone tell what all mistakes I made?

Comment: `sap.saved` instead of this use this `$scope.saved`

Comment: @uzaif if he is using `ng-controller="dataController as sap"` i think this is valid

Comment: when you use `$.param` what do you expect `$` to be?

Comment: ya @kiro112 you are right

Comment: just never user Jquery to get parameter from the view, since you have them in the $scope of angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data: $.param({'user' : $scope.sap }),`

should be

```
data: {
    'user': $scope.sap  //POST parameters
}
```

> data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions

Answer (score 4):

`$` is alias for `jQuery` and `param` is a [jquery method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/).

Have you included `jQuery`?

Comment: No. I removed jquery from everywhere. @Marco

Comment: Then you can avoid to use `$.param`, angular will take care to convert the object